How to display "Return to app" option in the "Return to Clock" watch menu?
I have a sports iOS app with a paired watch app, that uses location to update some UI elements. I technically need the location only when the watch app is in foreground, but since another requirement is to stop the clock from replacing the app, I decided to add background location checks. I followed the steps from the documentation (adding Background Modes to the watch extension target, setting allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates to true): the location update works fine, when I go to the clock, the app's icon is displayed in a circle at the top (bringing the app back to foreground on tap).
The only problem is that the "Return to app" option in the "Return to Clock" settings menu is missing, is there something I'm missing to display it?
Here's an example of what it looks like for the Strava app:

and how it looks for mine.

